# Does this language have a Pushdown Automata ( PDA )?

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-languages

the language is:  { A<sup>n</sup> B<sup>(2n)</sup> C<sup>n</sup> | where n>=0 }

I think it has, because you can process it like this: push A's, push B's, for each C pop three times from stack, if there are no C's and stack is empty, return true, else return false.

Comment: You'd probably get better answers here: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jpaugh- This is probably better at cs.stackexchange.com, since cstheory is for research-level CS questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the pumping lemma to prove this is not a context-free language.

Consider s = a<sup>p</sup> b<sup>2p</sup> c<sup>p</sup>
Then we consider `vxy`, `|vxy|<=p, |vy|>0` and uv<sup>i</sup>xy<sup>i</sup>z in L
We have the possibilities

> 1. vxy = a<sup>j</sup>, j<=p
> 2. vxy = a<sup>j</sup> b<sup>k</sup>, j+k<=p
> 3. vxy = b<sup>j</sup>, j<=p
> 4. vxy = b<sup>j</sup> c<sup>k</sup>, j+k<=p
> 5. vxy = c<sup>j</sup>, j <=p

In any case, there are no constants `u` and `v` s.t. the string is in L, because there can only be two symbols in `vxy` and we would then need a variable amount of the third to show in up `u` or `v`

Your proposed automata fails on AAAC, returning true. It doesn't guarantee that you have twice as many B's as A's.

Comment: thanks, I get it now, I can think of this language like this: A^n B^n B^n C^n , and then we lose 'n' in the popping of the first B's...

Answer (score 3):

No such PDA exists because this language is not context-free.  Here's a short proof of this.  This relies on the fact that context-free languages are closed under inverse homomorphism ([as mentioned in these slides](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/ialc/spr10/slides/cfl5.pdf)).

Given the language L = { A<sup>n</sup>B<sup>2n</sup>C<sup>n</sup> | n in N }, consider the homomorphism h defined from

- h(A) = A
- h(B) = BB
- h(C) = C

The inverse of this homomorphism, as applied to L, is the language h<sup>-1</sup>(L) = { x in Σ* | h(x) ∈ L }.  Looking over the choice of h, this is the language { A<sup>n</sup>B<sup>n</sup>C<sup>n</sup> | n in N }.  This language is a canonical example of a non-context-free language.  Howver, the CFLs are closed under inverse homomorphism, so because h<sup>-1</sup>(L) is not context-free, L cannot be context-free.  Therefore, there is no PDA for it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'd like to mark your answer as the final answer too, but I can't... thank you...