# Context free grammar for L{a^n b^m d^n where n>=0,m=2n

Tags: context-free-grammar, automata

Context free grammar for L{a^n b^m d^n where n>=0,m=2n

S -> ABD

A ->aB|a

B ->bB|b
D ->dd|dD

is this correct or not

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct. The shortest word I was able to produce using this grammar is `abdd` which does not conform to your language. It should have been possible to construct an empty word for n=0 and the word `abbd` for n=1.

**But:** The proposed language is not context free and cannot be described by a context free grammar. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491361/does-this-language-have-a-pushdown-automata-pda) answer for proof.

Answer (score -2):

CORRECT GRAMMAR

`Context free grammar for L{a^n b^m d^n where n>=0,m=2n`

S -> AbbBD | bb

```
  A ->aB|a
   B ->bB|b 
  D->dd|dD
```

Comment: This is not correct. Just one example: You could go from `S` directly to `bb` which is not a word of your language.